# INSERT from DataGridView in DB

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, datagridview, insert

my code only passes the first row to the database.
I am new to .NET. Who can suggest the problem.

```
                    for(int i = 0; i < dgvCSV_Datei.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        var strQuery = "INSERT INTO Mobile (Name, IMEI, Hersteller) VALUES (@Name, @IMEI, @Hersteller)";

                        sqlCommand.CommandText = strQuery;

                        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", dgvCSV_Datei.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);

                        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IMEI", dgvCSV_Datei.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);

                        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hersteller", dgvCSV_Datei.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);

                        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    }

                    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    sqlConnection.Close();
```

Comment: I would avoid [AddWithValue](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) but I would also not keep adding parameters in every iteration

Comment: Without `USING` clauses, I suspect that you are not disposing of your objects each iteration, making some what of a "mess".

Comment: Thank you, can you write in Code, please

Comment: I'd strongly suggest you use `SqlBulkCopy` instead, it's much much faster than individual inserts

Answer (score 0):

Your issue seems to be that you keep adding more parameters with the same name, without removing or changing the previous ones. Your code should instead look like this

```cs
const string strQuery = @"
INSERT INTO Mobile (Name, IMEI, Hersteller)
VALUES (@Name, @IMEI, @Hersteller);
";
using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(YourConnString))
using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(strQuery, sqlConnection))
{
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@IMEI", SqlDbType.Varchar, 16);
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Hersteller", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
    sqlConnection.Open();
    for(int i = 0; i < dgvCSV_Datei.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        sqlCommand.Parameters["@Name"].Value = dgvCSV_Datei.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
        sqlCommand.Parameters["@IMEI"].Value = dgvCSV_Datei.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value;
        sqlCommand.Parameters["@Hersteller"].Value = dgvCSV_Datei.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value;
        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

---

**A much better option is to use `SqlBulkCopy`.** This is a highly performant bulk-copy mechanism specifically for plain inserts.

```cs
using (var bulk = new SqlBulkCopy(YourConnString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.CheckConstraints | SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers))
{
    bulk.DestinationTableName = "Mobile";
    bulk.ColumnMappings.Add(dgvCSV_Datei.Columns[0].ColumnName, "Name");
    bulk.ColumnMappings.Add(dgvCSV_Datei.Columns[1].ColumnName, "IMEI");
    bulk.ColumnMappings.Add(dgvCSV_Datei.Columns[2].ColumnName, "Hersteller");
    bulk.WriteToServer(dgvCSV_Datei);
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!! The first is done. The second have a mistake (bulk.WriteToServer(dgvCSV_Datei(mistake));)

Comment: `dgvCSV_Datei` in that line would refer to a datatable. If it's actually a `DataGridView` then you probably want `dgvCSV_Datei.DataSource` or just refer to your base table object

Comment: dgvCSV_Datei yes DataGridView